# Collapse img tag when src path is wrong in XHTML1.0

Tags: image, src, xhtml-1.0-strict, onerror

I have an `img` tag. When the `src` path is wrong, I need to collapse the `img` tag. I can achieve this by using

> onerror

in HTML4. However, XHTML1.0 is not allowing the *onerror* attribute.

How can I achieve this in XHTML1.0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would the `src` path be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Manikandan, I don't get idea how you want to collapse the img tag. but I use the following technique to use onerror with valid xHTML validation to show the default picture if original picture not found using Javascript. See if it can help you.

```
<img src="sample.gif" alt="Test" id="testimg" />
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--CDATA
document.getElementById("testimg").onerror = function () { this.src='noimage.gif'; };
-->
</script>
```